# Yii routing module problems

Tags: php, yii

This is my module "auth"

```
-auth/
-controllers/
---AuthController.php
```

in controller I have action "register"

In layout I create route url:

> $this->createUrl('auth/auth/register')

Rules are in config/main.php

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        'register' => 'auth/auth/register',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

When I'm in *mySite/index.php* register url looks well: *mySite/register*. Url works and view is visible. When I'm this view *mySite/register* here starts a problem. Register url is *mySite/auth/auth/auth/register* - of course i see 404 error. 
Why it apeears and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the API page for createUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail)

> If the controller belongs to a module, the module ID will be prefixed
>   to the route. (If you do not want the module ID prefix, the route
>   should start with a slash '/'.)

Thus your code should read

```
$this->createUrl('/auth/auth/register')
```